# All events to a html instance are blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to edit a UI code but then am blocked in the following point.
Whatever  i do , am not able to pin any kind of event to the jquery object.

There are many objects with class name link. The following code is not having any kind of effect on the jquery object.

```
$(".link").on("click",function(x){alert("clicked")})
```

What could be a possible reason for this to happen.
I tested the code and could find out that $(".link") is returning a valid object.

Comment: Old jQuery version? Calling `.on()` before the element exists? Another element blocking the `.link` element? Another event stopping propagation? Need to see the whole code to say for sure.

Comment: and the specific jQuery Events, such as .click() don´t work either?

Comment: i tried them all , somehow events like clicking , mouse over and all are blocked

Comment: Maybe you didn't see this: "Need to see the whole code"

Comment: Care you explain what was the problem please?

Comment: In the code CSS of  pointer-events was set to none. because of this none of the event hook worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually attaching events like `.on("click", function(d, i){ console.log('clicked'); })` should work... but if thats not doing the job, there must be a css part for the edge, where  `pointer-events` will be set as none.. and removing this should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

One possible, and very likely, reason is that the code is being executed before the elements actually exist. Wrap the code in a `$(document).ready()` call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link").on("click",function(x){alert("clicked")});
});
```

Recommended reading:

- [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)

Comment: Not working on elements added on the fly (which is the whole purpose of `.on()`. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sz8qy/2/).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm well aware it won't work on dynamically added elements, but there's no indication in the question that it needs to. Not to mention that's not "the whole purpose" of `.on()`. The `.on()` function is for all event binding, both direct and delegated.

Comment: Does it have any advantage over `.click()` or `.bind("on")`?

Comment: @ShadowWizard In practice, they all do the same thing - `.bind("click")` and `.click()` call `.on("click")` in the background. Using `.on()` for everything is a consistent syntax, though, and is the function recommended in the jQuery API.

Comment: OK thanks, for some reason I was under the impression that `.on()` arrived to replace the `.live()`.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be common confusion with the `.on()`. In case of dynamically added elements, you should apply the `.on()` on the parent (that exists when the document is ready) and put a scope as the second argument of the `.on()` method.

In your case it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "div.link", function(x){alert("clicked")})
});
```

This will also work for such elements created on the fly. [Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Sz8qy/1/).